# Why is this array being logged as undefined when it seems properly scoped?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, scope

To start, I'm new to JS and I'm working through this problem and had nowhere else to turn.

I'm working with modernizr to switch image sources to and from .webp to speed up website loading.
basically, my problem is with variable scope and setting the sources of the images in an empty array.

The code looks like this:

```html
 <script>
      /*! modernizr 3.6.0 (Custom Build) | MIT *
 * https://modernizr.com/download/?-webp-setclasses !*/
!function(e,n,A){function o(e){var n=u.className,A=Modernizr._config.classPrefix||"";if(c&&(n=n.baseVal),Modernizr._config.enableJSClass){var o=new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+A+"no-js(\\s|$)");n=n.replace(o,"$1"+A+"js$2")}Modernizr._config.enableClasses&&(n+=" "+A+e.join(" "+A),c?u.className.baseVal=n:u.className=n)}function t(e,n){return typeof e===n}function a(){var e,n,A,o,a,i,l;for(var f in r)if(r.hasOwnProperty(f)){if(e=[],n=r[f],n.name&&(e.push(n.name.toLowerCase()),n.options&&n.options.aliases&&n.options.aliases.length))for(A=0;A<n.options.aliases.length;A++)e.push(n.options.aliases[A].toLowerCase());for(o=t(n.fn,"function")?n.fn():n.fn,a=0;a<e.length;a++)i=e[a],l=i.split("."),1===l.length?Modernizr[l[0]]=o:(!Modernizr[l[0]]||Modernizr[l[0]]instanceof Boolean||(Modernizr[l[0]]=new Boolean(Modernizr[l[0]])),Modernizr[l[0]][l[1]]=o),s.push((o?"":"no-")+l.join("-"))}}function i(e,n){if("object"==typeof e)for(var A in e)f(e,A)&&i(A,e[A]);else{e=e.toLowerCase();var t=e.split("."),a=Modernizr[t[0]];if(2==t.length&&(a=a[t[1]]),"undefined"!=typeof a)return Modernizr;n="function"==typeof n?n():n,1==t.length?Modernizr[t[0]]=n:(!Modernizr[t[0]]||Modernizr[t[0]]instanceof Boolean||(Modernizr[t[0]]=new Boolean(Modernizr[t[0]])),Modernizr[t[0]][t[1]]=n),o([(n&&0!=n?"":"no-")+t.join("-")]),Modernizr._trigger(e,n)}return Modernizr}var s=[],r=[],l={_version:"3.6.0",_config:{classPrefix:"",enableClasses:!0,enableJSClass:!0,usePrefixes:!0},_q:[],on:function(e,n){var A=this;setTimeout(function(){n(A[e])},0)},addTest:function(e,n,A){r.push({name:e,fn:n,options:A})},addAsyncTest:function(e){r.push({name:null,fn:e})}},Modernizr=function(){};Modernizr.prototype=l,Modernizr=new Modernizr;var f,u=n.documentElement,c="svg"===u.nodeName.toLowerCase();!function(){var e={}.hasOwnProperty;f=t(e,"undefined")||t(e.call,"undefined")?function(e,n){return n in e&&t(e.constructor.prototype[n],"undefined")}:function(n,A){return e.call(n,A)}}(),l._l={},l.on=function(e,n){this._l[e]||(this._l[e]=[]),this._l[e].push(n),Modernizr.hasOwnProperty(e)&&setTimeout(function(){Modernizr._trigger(e,Modernizr[e])},0)},l._trigger=function(e,n){if(this._l[e]){var A=this._l[e];setTimeout(function(){var e,o;for(e=0;e<A.length;e++)(o=A[e])(n)},0),delete this._l[e]}},Modernizr._q.push(function(){l.addTest=i}),Modernizr.addAsyncTest(function(){function e(e,n,A){function o(n){var o=n&&"load"===n.type?1==t.width:!1,a="webp"===e;i(e,a&&o?new Boolean(o):o),A&&A(n)}var t=new Image;t.onerror=o,t.onload=o,t.src=n}var n=[{uri:"data:image/webp;base64,UklGRiQAAABXRUJQVlA4IBgAAAAwAQCdASoBAAEAAwA0JaQAA3AA/vuUAAA=",name:"webp"},{uri:"data:image/webp;base64,UklGRkoAAABXRUJQVlA4WAoAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAQUxQSAwAAAABBxAR/Q9ERP8DAABWUDggGAAAADABAJ0BKgEAAQADADQlpAADcAD++/1QAA==",name:"webp.alpha"},{uri:"data:image/webp;base64,UklGRlIAAABXRUJQVlA4WAoAAAASAAAAAAAAAAAAQU5JTQYAAAD/////AABBTk1GJgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGQAAABWUDhMDQAAAC8AAAAQBxAREYiI/gcA",name:"webp.animation"},{uri:"data:image/webp;base64,UklGRh4AAABXRUJQVlA4TBEAAAAvAAAAAAfQ//73v/+BiOh/AAA=",name:"webp.lossless"}],A=n.shift();e(A.name,A.uri,function(A){if(A&&"load"===A.type)for(var o=0;o<n.length;o++)e(n[o].name,n[o].uri)})}),a(),o(s),delete l.addTest,delete l.addAsyncTest;for(var p=0;p<Modernizr._q.length;p++)Modernizr._q[p]();e.Modernizr=Modernizr}(window,document);     
      </script>
      
      
      <script>
      
       let imagesornot = [];
        
        Modernizr.on('webp', function(result) {
          
  if (result) {
    
  
  imagesornot = ['https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal1.webp?v=1595534871429',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal2.webp?v=1595534875205',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal3.webp?v=1595534879142',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal4.webp?v=1595534876818',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal5.webp?v=1595534878825',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal6.webp?v=1595534871344',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal7.webp?v=1595534871504',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal8.webp?v=1595534873717',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal9.webp?v=1595534870152',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal10.webp?v=1595534879559',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal11.webp?v=1595534881443',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal12.webp?v=1595534871717',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal13.webp?v=1595534872813',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal14.webp?v=1595534871632',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal15.webp?v=1595534873058',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal16.webp?v=1595534872744',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal17.webp?v=1595534878192',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal18.webp?v=1595534881444',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal19.webp?v=1595534875846',
                                           'https://cdn.glitch.com/4ead142d-246b-4550-8218-d7130a244dd5%2Fpersonal20.webp?v=1595534873320'];
    
    console.log('webp supported!!!');
      
      
  } else {
    
    
      imagesornot = ['https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F1.jpg?v=1592359818160',
                                      'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F2.jpg?v=1592359846105',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F3.jpg?v=1592359853602',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F4.jpg?v=1592359832791',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F5.jpg?v=1592359855106',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F6.jpg?v=1592359811311',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F7.jpg?v=1592359798911',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F8.jpg?v=1592359813220',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F9.jpg?v=1592359796677',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F10.jpg?v=1592359838355',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F11.jpg?v=1592359856005',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F12.jpg?v=1592359799909',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F13.jpg?v=1592359807718',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F14.jpg?v=1592359800816',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F15.jpg?v=1592359802183',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F16.jpg?v=1592359804323',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F17.jpg?v=1592359832924',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F18.jpg?v=1592359839887',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F19.jpg?v=1592359847898',
                                       'https://cdn.glitch.com/04361456-6f86-4ef7-b7f9-c7534267cc09%2F20.jpg?v=1592359805910'
                                      ];
  }} )
        
        console.log(imagesornot); //why does this log as an empty array??
          
          
      
    
      </script>
```

Really, what I'm wondering is why this array logs as an empty array *after* it's been populated, and also how do I fix this?

Comment: The part of your code where you are setting the array is an event and is asynchronous. When the javascript interpreter reaches your console log, the event hasn't populated the array yet. It's not till shortly after that the array gets populated.

Comment: The value of `imagesornot` is not set until `Modernizr.on` happens first.

Comment: Change   `}} )  console.log(imagesornot);` to `console.log(imagesornot);  }} );` so the `console.log` is in the Event function. That Event isn't happening until after your original `console.log(imagesornot);`, like @Chris pointed out... Asynchronously.